# Export netstat data from terminal to csv file

Tags: scripting, terminal, csv

having a bit of an issue, i am looking to create a script which runs the following command every 60 seconds

```
netstat - tn
```

which should give an output like

```
root@guest:~# netstat -tn
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0    111 111.111.141.36:22         111.11.11.223:54327      ESTABLISHED
```

and i am only interested in storing the foreign address, how can i achieve this?

i did try the following command

root@guest:~# watch -n 300 netstat -tn > results_mon_27.txt

to log all the data into a text file, but this caused issues with the formatting as seen below, so would be best if i only collected the foreign address

```
^[[?1049h^[[1;40r^[(B^[[m^[[4l^[[?7h^[[H^[[2JEvery 300.0s: netstat -tn^[[1;138Hguest: Mon Aug 21 16:45:31 2017^[[3;1HActive Internet connections (w/o servers)
^[[4dProto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address^[[4;45HForeign Address^[[4;69HState
^[[5dtcp^[[5;12H0^[[19G0 45.76.141.36:38708^[[45G192.42.115.102:9004     TIME_WAIT
^[[6dtcp^[[6;12H0     40 45.76.141.36:22^[[6;45H193.36.8.223:54327^[[69GESTABLISHED^[[40;168H^[[1;159H50^[[5;34H22   ^[[5;47H3.36.8.223:54327      ESTABLISHED^[[6;18H6$
^[[5d^[[M^[[1;160H5
^[[6dtcp^[[6;12H0^[[19G0 45.76.141.36:22^[[6;45H58.242.83.32:25719^[[69GESTABLISHED^[[40;168H
^[[6d^[[J^[[1;159H10^[[40;168H
^[[5d^[[L^[[1;160H5
^[[5dtcp^[[5;12H0^[[19G0 45.76.141.36:22^[[5;45H196.200.176.80:37384    ESTABLISHED
^[[7dtcp^[[7;12H0^[[19G0 45.76.141.36:22^[[7;45H58.242.83.32:61038^[[69GESTABLISHED^[[40;168H
^[[5d^[[M^[[1;159H20^[[6;58H49490^[[40;168H^[[1;160H5^[[6;34H38722^[[45G192.42.115.102:9004
^[[7dtcp^[[7;12H0     68 45.76.141.36:22^[[7;45H58.242.83.32:42510^[[69GESTABLISHED^[[40;168H^[[1;159H30^[[7;18H 0^[[7;58H38678^[[40;168H
^[[7d^[[J^[[1;160H5^[[5;45H58.242.83.32:15804^[[6;34H22   ^[[6;47H3.36.8.223:54327 ^[[40;168H
^[[5d^[[M^[[1;159H40
^[[6dtcp^[[6;12H0^[[19G0 45.76.141.36:22^[[6;45H58.242.83.32:14118^[[69GESTABLISHED^[[40;168H^[[1;160H5^[[6;60H003
```

Answer (score 2):

since the Foreign Address is the 5th column try the output of `netstat` with `awk` you can colect/manipulate data per column easy.

```
netstat -tn|awk '{print $5}'
```

the output will provide you only the fith colum that is the Foreign Address

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    netstat -tn|awk '{print $5}' >> output.netstat
    sleep 60
done
```